# Como puedo realizar un arreglo apartir de una informacion mal agrupada en una consulta sql desde node.js?

Tags: javascript, sql, nodejs

actualmente tengo realizada una api desde node.js, este a su vez llama a procedimiento almacenados en una base de datos SQL y llamando a cierta ruta(en node.js) con ciertos parametros, está vendria a ejecutar el SPC...
El problema que tengo es que la consulta, no me agrupa los datos, y necesito agruparlos en node.js...
Por ejemplo la consulta me retorna este resultado:

```
<pre>
<code>
| nombre | apellido | edad |  ciudad  |pago|detallesP| detallesP2 

  luis      gonzales    45    santiago  300    R1900   R1901
  luis      gonzales    45    santiago  600    R2900   R1902
  alberto   gonzales3   46    santiago  500    R1300   R1301
  oracio    gonzales4   44    santiago  600    R1600   R1601
  fernando  gonzales5   43    santiago  700    R1700   R1700
</code>
</pre>


Por lo tanto tendré un resultado en .json de este ejemplo asi:

<pre>
<code>
[{
nombre: 'luis',
apellidos: 'gonzales',
edad: 45,
ciudad 'santiago',
pago: 300,
detallesP: 'R1900',
detallesP2: 'R1901',
},
{
nombre: 'luis',
apellidos: 'gonzales',
edad: 45,
ciudad 'santiago',
pago: 600,
detallesP: 'R2900',
detallesP2: 'R1902',
...
]
</code>
</pre>

Y el resultado esperando seria:

<pre>
<code>
[{
nombre: 'luis',
apellidos: 'gonzales',
edad: 45,
ciudad 'santiago',
pagos: {
pago: 300,
pago: 600},
DetallesP : [
{detallesP: 'R1900',
 detallesP2: 'R1901'},
{detallesP: 'R2900',
 detallesP2: 'R1901'}]
},

]
</code>
</pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

Creo que tendrías que hacer lo siguiente

1.- Agrupar los elementos en un único arreglo usando como diferenciado: nombre, apellidos, edad, ciudad. Esto es para obtener la cantidad de 'pagos' y detalles

2.- Recorrer el arreglo anterior para sacar la información que necesitas y guardarla en las variables correspondientes (pagos, DetallesP)

Así a groso modo

Comment: con reduce o tienes algun otro metodo?